# If $F^{\times}$ has a subgroup of order 17, then the smallest possible order of the field $F$

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field and $F^{\times}$ be the group of all nonzero elements of $F$ under multiplication. If $F^{\times}$ has a subgroup of order 17, then what is the smallest possible order of the field $F$?

Give me some hints to solve this!!

Comment: Hint: you need to find the smallest prime power of the form $17n + 1$. Do you see why?

Comment: thank you, it is follows from Lagrange's theorem

Comment: tbh I don't see a non-brute-force way of calculating the smallest such number. Of course, you can see that $2^{16} = 1\pmod{17}$ because of Lagrange's theorem, and now you only have to check all number smaller than $2^{16} = 256$. But then you still have to brute-force check all these primes, or is there some smarter way to do this?

Comment: @student91 there's not many to check.   Btw it's $2^{\color {blue}{8}}=256$.

Comment: it's 103 I believe

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a hint: $\#(F^\times) = \#(F) - 1$, and by Lagrange's theorem, you must have $17 \mid \# (F^\times)$. Now, what do you know about the possible sizes of $\#F$ where $F$ is a finite field?

Answer (score 1):

$103$ appears to be the smallest prime which is $1+17k$.  Just checking by hand.

So it's the smallest,  since powers of primes get bigger right away. You just check $2,3,5,7$, and none of their powers give a smaller number. (Remember,  finite fields have orders a power of a prime.)